# Postgresql - Sum JSON rows on matching keys

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have two columns in my database, one of uid (myuid) and another of key value pairs representing total pets per user (totalpetsjson). I would like to query on uid and then sum the resulting JSON rows where keys match.

This query

```
SELECT totalpetsjson FROM mytable WHERE "myuid" IN ('john','andy')
```

Results in two rows

```
{'dogs':3,'cats':5,'fish':144}
{'dogs':2,'lizards':4,'cats':3'}
```

What I want the result to be. How could I query and combine the above two rows to look like below?

```
{'dogs':5,'cats':8,'fish':144,'lizards':4}
```

Comment: What is your specific question? What have you attempted?

Comment: @Nick - My specific question is "How do I sum multiple json rows together where keys match?". Should it be phrased differently? I am relatively new to postgresql and don't know where to start on this

Comment: And what have you attempted? You should show your effort and where you need help, otherwise this looks like you are simply asking others to do the work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function [`json_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) which gives pairs `(key, value)`, cast `values` to integer and sum them in groups by `keys`. Finally, aggregate the results to json:

```
select json_object_agg(key, sum)
from (
    select key, sum(value::int)
    from my_table 
    cross join json_each_text(totalpetsjson)
    where myuid in ('john','andy') 
    group by key
    ) s

                     json_object_agg                     
---------------------------------------------------------
 { "fish" : 144, "lizards" : 4, "cats" : 8, "dogs" : 5 }
(1 row)
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Xxv82Jd)

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of the previous anwser by klin, that approach can be expanded if you're not interested in flattening a full table but keeping a grouping:

```sql
SELECT x, json_object_agg(key, sum)
FROM (
    SELECT x, key, sum(value::INT) AS sum
    FROM (
        VALUES (1, '{
          "a": 10,
          "b": 11
        }'::JSONB),
        (1, '{
          "b": 12,
          "c": 13
        }'::JSONB),
        (2, '{
          "b": 14,
          "c": 15
        }'::JSONB)
    ) AS mytable(x, y)
             CROSS JOIN jsonb_each_text(Y)
    GROUP BY 1, 2
) x
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Result:

```
1,"{ ""c"" : 13, ""b"" : 23, ""a"" : 10 }"
2,"{ ""c"" : 15, ""b"" : 14 }"
```